# Consume Restful WCF service in asp.net mvc 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm totally new with asp.net mvc. I'm having trouble consuming rest web service in asp.net mvc4 app.

This is the interface of the service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetRuleDetail/{id}")]
    string GetRuleDetail(string id);
}
```

In my mvc app I've added my service as service reference "ServiceReference1"

Then I've created a controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string strjson = Request["Json"].ToString();
        //string strjson = "input={\"name\": \"obj1\",\"x\": 11,\"y\":20,\"obj\":{\"testKey\":\"val\",},\"tab\":[1 , 2, 46]}";
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        return View(obj.GetRuleDetail(strjson));
    }
```

The string strjson, I want to pass it from the view which has the following code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";} <h2>Index</h2> <section class="contact">
<header>
    <h3>Enter your JSON string</h3>
</header>
<p>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Json")
            @Html.TextBox("txtJson")
        </li>
    </ol>
</p>
<p>
    <button>Test</button>
</p>
```

Am I missing something? Cz strjson is always null and the Index() method is executed before I enter my jsonstring in the textbox. How can I fix that plz

Comment: And what will be value of Textbox and id of something which will be then passed to service ?

Comment: I want the user to enter a string in the textbox, and this string would be used as the id to call the service method GetRuleDetail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not right approach first you need to render a view than you will post it to server along with id which will then be passed to service.You need to create a model which will be binded to view.

First render view

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View();//Tihs will simply return view
}
```

This is model class by which view will be binded

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

This will be your view

```
 @model JsonData

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetServiceData", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
        @Html.Label("Json")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Id)
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

Now when you will post this view it will go to controller along with data in textbox

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetServiceData(JsonData model)
{
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    return View(obj.GetRuleDetail(model.Id));//Tihs will simply return view
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was really confused.
But one more question, how do I create this view? usually it's a right click inside the ActionResult.

Comment: You can click on Views folder and click Add View.

Comment: Sorry for these stupid questions. But I don't understand how would that match each ActionResult to its view?

Comment: It will automatically match the action name with view name view name and action name must be same otherwise you can do this as well return View(viewname);

Comment: So I create 2 views. one for Index and one for GetServiceData, both with the same code?

Comment: Yes one would be for getting input from user and in second you will display result returned from webservice.